# How to attach files to apple mail compose window?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am able to create a new outgoing message and then attach files to it but not able to attach to already opened compose window, how can get the hook to opened compose window and then attach files. Below is the code which I used to attach files by creating new compose window

```
 set userName to short user name of (system info)
 set theAttachmentFolder to "/Users/" & userName & "/Documents/Test/" as POSIX file as alias
 tell application "Finder" to set attchList to get every file of folder (theAttachmentFolder)

 tell application "Mail"
 set msg to make new outgoing message with properties{visible:true}
 tell msg
    repeat with attach in attchList

    make new attachment with properties {file name:(contents of attach as alias)}
 end repeat

 end tell

 end tell
```

Comment: Mail does not provide a way to get ID of a new message not yet saved (as draft) of sent.You can only see there is a front window, but it is not attached to any document or object. Only when user will have saved the new email as draft, then you can gets its ID via drafts mailbox. the work around is to use GUI scripting simulate add file menu command (keys Cmd / shift A). Then you must use standard cmd G (go to folder) and select your file via system event keys. ...or you must asked user to save its message as draft to get its ID

Comment: It would be helpful if I can I get any official documentation for this so that I can conclude.Thanks

Comment: There is no official documentation about non existing feature of Mail in Applescript. in Script Editor, you can only see Mail dictionary and here there is not object to describe non yet registered email. Finally, the easiest is probably to do the opposite : run first the script which make new message with attached file and then leave users to complete and send it.